# How to find an analytic extension of a function?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example, the function is $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z-i)}{z^2+1}$. Could you also list a general procedure to find an analytic extension?

Kavi says the $f(z)$ above can't be extended. Under what circumstances we can find an analytic extension of a function?

Since $f(z)$ can't be extended, what about $g(z)=\frac{1}{e^{2z}-1}$? Or you may like to use another (nontrivial) example to illustrate that.

Comment: The function is analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{-i\}$ it cannot be extended beyond this.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Under what circumstances we can find an analytic extension?

Comment: The question is too general. Finding analytic extension can be very hard and tricky.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What about my second toy function $g$? Can we find an analytic extension for that?

Comment: Almost like $f$, but with a infinite number of poles. Both of your examples are trivial. Interesting example: the zeta function defined as the sum of the Dirichlet series.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, in fact $f$ also has has a *removable* singularity at $z = i$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, I am aware of that.